# Survey Question Validity

Tags: survey, mean, validity

I have a survey that asks the user to report their debt from their undergraduate education and their debt from their graduate education. I intend to add these two averages to measure their average total debt.

The population for my survey is 150 students from a past graduating class. 
I had 70 responses to the question about undergraduate debt and 50 responses to the question about the graduate debt.

When finding the average total debt, I was wondering if I should average the debt from people that responded to both questions, or if I can simply add the two averages.

I feel like validity improves if I only use those that responded to both questions. But at the same time, I feel like both averages are working point estimates, so I shouldn't need to worry about this issue.

What do you think?

EDIT: Each individual reports their debt from their undergraduate and graduate degrees. The post originally said that each individual reports their average. My mistake!

Comment: Why is there a difference in the responses? Is it because those 20 students did not have graduate debt? Or they did not answer that question? Also, why did you ask for the "average" debt and what does that mean? Why not total debt?

Comment: How can an individual have an "average debt"? Each person owes what they owe - there is nothing to average. Also, I'd be very worried about nonresponse -your respondents are unlikely to be a random sample. And ... you need to tell us why some people reported only one debt and not the other.

Comment: @PeterFlom Forgive me! Each individual reports the debt they had upon finishing their undergraduate degree and their graduate degree. I agree that because of the non-response, the respondents may not compose a random sample. How do you think I should proceed?

Comment: @user2974951 Non-response! If they had no debt, they would have put 0 (this was said explicitly in the survey question).

Comment: Then you should add them rather than take the average - total debt. As for the missing values, this may be a problem, biased sample.

Comment: I agree with @user2974951 - total debt, not average. As for the missing data - I'd be reasonably sure it *is* a problem. Then you have to figure out how to cope. That's going to be hard. Even a small amount of missing data can mess things up if it is seriously biased. So, you may want to look at the median of all the students, rather than the mean, as the median is very resistant to outliers.